# How to re-order vector values based on the sort-order from another vector in haskell?

Tags: sorting, haskell, vector

suppose i have two vectors:

```
  let x = V.fromList ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  let y = V.fromList [1,3,2]
```

I want to define a vector `y'` which is the sorted version of `y`, but I also want to defined a reordered `x'` which is ordered based on the sort ordering of `y` (`x'` should look like `["foo", "baz", "bar"]`).

What's the best function to do that? Ideally, I want to avoid writing sorting functions from scratch.

Comment: `V.fromList $ sortOn  snd (V.toList (V.zip x y))`

Comment: @pdexter, wouldn't using a sort from `vector-algorithms` along with `Data.Vector.Modify` be faster than converting to a list, sorting, and converting back?

Comment: @dfeuer, yes, most likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list-based way:

```
> import Data.List
> let x = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
> let y = [1,3,2]
> map snd . sort $ zip y x
["foo","baz","bar"]
```

Basically, we zip so to obtain a list of pairs

```
[(1,"foo"),(3,"bar"),(2,"baz")]
```

Then we sort it, lexicographically, so that the first component matters more.

Finally, we discard the first components.

You should be able to adapt this to vectors as well.

Comment: is there a go-to drop-in replacement for Data.List (sort)? Most sorting functionality for vector seems to be intended for mutable / boxed variants.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [`backpermute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:backpermute)

> ```
> backpermute :: Vector a -> Vector Int -> Vector a
> ```
>
> *O(n)* Yield the vector obtained by replacing each element `i` of the index vector by `xs!i`. This is equivalent to `map (xs!)` is but is often much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Sort a vector of *indices* comparing indexed values; then [permute](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:backpermute) both vectors based on sorted indices. [Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Intro.html) provides 
[introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) for mutable vectors and [`modify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:18) provides safe destructive updates using [ST Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html).

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro (sortBy)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (generate, modify)
import Data.Vector (Vector, unsafeIndex, backpermute, convert, fromList)
import qualified Data.Vector as V

reorder :: (Ord b) => Vector a -> Vector b -> (Vector a, Vector b)
reorder a b = (backpermute a idx, backpermute b idx)
    where
    idx  = convert $ modify (sortBy comp) init
    comp = comparing $ unsafeIndex b  -- comparing function
    init = generate (V.length b) id   -- [0..size - 1]
```

then,

```
\> reorder (fromList ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) $ fromList [1, 3, 2]
(["foo","baz","bar"],[1,2,3])
```